# Android device not found

Tags: android

I'm trying to build "Hello, Android" with the Android SDK, but Android won't say "hello" to me.

I build with the 2.6 version of the SDK and run in Eclipse on Win XP.  (I've installed the plug-in.)

Here's what I get:

> [2009-09-23 16:35:19 -
>   HelloAndroid]Android Launch!
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:19 -
>   HelloAndroid]adb is running normally.
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:19 -
>   HelloAndroid]Performing
>   com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid
>   activity launch
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:19 -
>   HelloAndroid]Automatic Target Mode:
>   launching new emulator with compatible
>   AVD 'my_avd'
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:19 -
>   HelloAndroid]Launching a new emulator
>   with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:21 -
>   HelloAndroid]New emulator found:
>   emulator-5554
>
> [2009-09-23 16:35:21 -
>   HelloAndroid]Waiting for HOME
>   ('android.process.acore') to be
>   launched...
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:20 -
>   HelloAndroid]HOME is up on device
>   'emulator-5554'
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:20 -
>   HelloAndroid]Uploading
>   HelloAndroid.apk onto device
>   'emulator-5554'
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:30 -
>   HelloAndroid]Installing
>   HelloAndroid.apk...
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:43 -
>   HelloAndroid]Success!
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:44 -
>   HelloAndroid]Starting activity
>   com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid
>   on device
>
> [2009-09-23 16:36:44 -
>   HelloAndroid]Launch ***error***:
>   device (emulator-5554) request
>   rejected: ***device not found***

Comment: At the time of writing this question, there is no such thing as "2.6 version of the SDK". Was it 1.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.  It may be a timing issue.  Have to press Menu button on emulator keypad to unlock the screen.  Then the output is displayed.